Extend graph $G$ to be Hamiltonian graph
I want to create an algorithm that finds the smallest (by number of edges) Hamiltonian graph $G'$, a subgraph of graph G (same vertices, some additional edges).
I already know how to find a Hamiltonian cycle. I have some idea how to approximate solutions (using Dirac's Theorem). But I'm not sure how to approach finding the most optimal solution (least number of additional edges).
Is there any paper related to this problem? I greatly appreciate all the tips.

You're addressing the Hamiltonian Completion Problem, which involves adding the fewest edges to a graph $(G)$ to make it Hamiltonian (i.e., containing a Hamiltonian cycle).

Hamiltonian Completion Problem: Given a graph $( G = (V, E) )$, find the smallest set of edges $( E')$ such that $( G' = (V, E \cup E') )$ has a Hamiltonian cycle. Here is the wikipedia

The problem is NP-hard, meaning that exact solutions are computationally intensive for large graphs. This necessitates heuristic or approximation methods for practical purposes.


